# How to remove delay?

Tags: arduino

I am working on a very important project that needs to have maximum efficiency and speed. Basically I use the serial ports of Arduino to communicate to a SIM900 GSM, but I think this can apply to any other device that is connected to the Serial port of Arduino. The problem is that after each command I send to the SIM900 I put a delay because I don't know how much time it will take to be executed, but sometimes commands can be executed really fast or really slow. My question is: How can I display the output of the SIM900 WITHOUT using the delay but maybe a do {} while; a cycle that checks if something new needs to be displayed? I would appreciate if you guys could help me. Thank You!

Here are some commands I used for the serial communication:

```
 myGsm.begin(19200);  
 Serial.begin(9600);  
 delay(500);

 myGsm.println("AT+CGATT=1");
 delay(200);



 printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");//setting the SAPBR,connection type is GPRS
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();


 myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet.wind\"");//setting the APN,2nd parameter empty works for all networks 
 delay(5000);
 printSerialData();


 myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");
 delay(1000);
printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
 delay(10000);
printSerialData();

 myGsm.println("AT+HTTPINIT"); //init the HTTP request
 delay(2000); 
printSerialData();


void printSerialData()
{
 while(myGsm.available()!=0)
 Serial.write(myGsm.read());
}
```

Comment: use readBytes or readBytesUntil. this functions wait for the input, but not longer then necessary

Comment: Try to be more specific here. Show your actual code and some messages you are receiving.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I have modified the post by adding some code, you can take a look.

Comment: What is ```myGsm```?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg myGsm has been declared by the function SoftwareSerial myGsm(7,8); It basically tells arduino that pin 7 is for input to the SIM900(GSM) and pin 8 is the OUTPUT from the SIM900

Comment: If you need efficiency and speed, you shouldn't be using the Arduino libraries at all.  They're ridiculously bloated, inefficient, and slow.

Comment: @TomServo Interesting...I am sure Tom that you have more experience than me, but if you say that I shouldn't use Arduino libraries, then what should I use? Is there something more efficient/better?

Comment: @AestheticCode Yes, the Arduino libraries are woefully bloated and slow compared to pure C or assembly language.  I prefer C for this class of controller.  There are many very efficient and lean libraries available for serial communications using C; search for them online or in other forums that specialize in support for the AVR family of controllers.

Comment: I never knew about that, I am going to take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem. One way is a blocking loop until data was received:

```
void printSerialData()
{
    //Block until data is received
    while(myGsm.available() <= 0);

    //Get received
    while(myGsm.available() > 0)
    {
        while(myGsm.available() > 0)
        {
            Serial.write(myGsm.read());
        }
        //Give chance to receive more
        delay(10);
    }
}
```

An alternative way makes use of the fact, that AT commands are typically finalized by `\r\n`. This means you can try to receive data until the final `\n`. Make use of [readBytesUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytesuntil/) or [readStringUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/) like:

```
void printSerialData()
{
    String read = myGsm.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.write(read);
}
```

Don't forget to set a correct timeout by calling [setTimeout](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/) before.

Comment: I really got it working...! I've literally been searching for a long time on the internet but never got the answer...You helped me improve the UI of my project by A LOT...Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am very pleased with the solutions you provided but I've run into a problem. Basically I used the second solution (the one with readStringUntil) and I've set the timeout to 100 at the beginning of the setup function... But when I get to the last 2 commands which are AT+HTTPACTION=0 and AT+HTTPREAD=0,20
the function simply doesn't return what it should because it seems like it doesn't have enough time, It works fine if I add a delay of 8000ms but we are back theaa first problem...This way the code takes way longer than it really needs to.

Comment: So whats the problem increasing the timeout?

Comment: If I increase the timeout to around 8000ms it works fine but sometimes the results can come in even faster and I want to make it in a way so it gives enough time for the response to come but IF it is possible without using the delay...

Comment: The timeout is a fallback value. This means it is the maximum amount of time to wait. In case of the end character is received faster, the method returns.